# Shorthand for if sentence

Tags: javascript, optimization, shorthand

**Why I am asking**

I have been having a lot of trouble understanding the shorthand for the `if` sentence in JavaScript, and I haven't found an article or tutorial that described it well. And that's why I am stuck opitimizing my little code. And I am new to JavaScript, so if someone could give me a basic understanding of the shortning of this code, I would very much appreciate you telling me the magic behind the code.

**What I need help with**

I am going to use the exact same code in a lot of functions. Therefore, I want to optimize it and make it shorter version of the code.

```
function welcomemessage() {
if (br == 1) {
hello();
}
else {
hey();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even shorter:

```
function welcomemessage(br){
    [hello,hey][br-1]();    //This will work.
}
welcomemessage(1);  //hello();
welcomemessage(2);  //hey();
```

---

**Fun Fact:**<sup>**1**</sup>

To make your script hard to read for someone else, do it like this:

```
function welcomemessage(){
    return br==1 && (hello(),1) || (hey(),1);    //This will work too.
}
```

<sub><sup>**1**</sup> Totally not related to the answer.</sub>

---

### Update

```
var something = ( (br == 1) ? hello() : hey() );
```

`something` will be the value `hello()` or `hey()` returned.

Comment: This will wrongly call `hello()` if `br` is 2. Or I might be wrong. JS casting is confusing

Comment: Well, I was assuming there is only two choices.

Comment: So, I can just call this as a variable as I assume I would only use the two values. Like var something = ((br == 1) ? hello() : hey();)

Comment: `something` will then be the value `hello()` or `hey()` returned.

Comment: Make a variable like this;
`var check = br ? hello(); : hey();`

and call it something like this:
`if(check==1) {hello();}
if(check==2) {hey();}`

Comment: Remove the `;` after `hello()`.

Comment: Oh, that explayins alot! Let's say I did not have any of these hello or hey's, it would just be true or false, like this:

`var something = ( (br == 1) ? (true) : (false) );`
or
`var something = ( (br == 1) ? (1) : (0) );`

and call it like this
`if(something==1) {/*do if 1*/} else{/*do if something else than 1*/}`

Comment: @user1431627 - Yes, and actually you can do this since it is either `1` or `0`: `if(something){}`

Comment: Hm... well. That dose not reduce the file size. I would just add it as a normal `(br == 1) ? /*if 1*/ : /*something else*/;`, then?

Comment: But one more question: Why would this code not work?

`function help() {(br == 1) list = ["listofarrayshere"]; hello() : list = ["listofarrayshere"]; hey();}`

Comment: Try this: `function help() {(br == 1)?(list = ["listofarrayshere"], hello()) :( list = ["listofarrayshere"], hey());}`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Do you know if whenever or not this is faster than a normal if scentence?

Comment: [It seems like ternary operators are a little bit faster.](http://jsperf.com/ternary-operators-vs-if)

Comment: Thank you! I looked in a thread about the use of tilde in JavaScript, but no real answers was there. Would you recomend me using `Math.floor` or `~~`?

Comment: @user1431627 - Wow, I didn't know there is `~~` in JavaScript! Thanks for teaching me that.

Answer (score 6):

Use the ternary operator.

```
function welcomemessage() {  
  (br == 1) ? hello() : hey();
}
```

The ternary operator is useful, and not difficult to understand. here's how it works.

```
(condition) ? (true) : (false)
```

Edit:

Since JS treats functions as first class objects, it is possible to create a wrapper. Something like below (not tested though)

```
function ternaryWrapper(br, functionTrue, functionFalse){
   return (br == 1) ? functionTrue : functionFalse;
}

//call it
ternaryWrapper(2,hello, hey);
```

Comment: Is there a way to just call it for future references. I am using the `br` variable all the time in every function. The only thing I am going to change is `hello();` and `hey();`.

Comment: I can also add an Array to the calling. (a really large one)

Comment: Hm. I dose not seem to work when adding two things in it. An Array and a function call.

Comment: It won't work with an array since doing `array == 1` will give unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
var msgfuncs = [ hey, hello ];
function welcommessage() { msgfuncs[br](); }
```

(assumes that when "br" isn't 1 it's 0, which of course may be an invalid assumption.)

If the choice is made with different functions, just put the array directly in the surrounding function:

```
function welcomemessage() {
  [ hey, hello ][br]();
}
```

If you want to make the decision and save the function to call later, you can do this:

```
var messageFunction = [ hey, hello ][ br ];
```

then any time later:

```
messageFunction();
```

Comment: Is there a way to just make a variable with the shortning and just call it? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you exactly, but I'll add to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case `br` is always be numeric, the xbonez answer can be optimized a little bit by using strict comparison `===` (because it is a little bit faster):

```
function welcomemessage() {
    (br === 1) ? hello() : hey();
}
```

And another interesting option is:

```
function welcomemessage() {
    (br - 1) ? hey() : hello();
}
```

This last function works because when `br` is `1`, it will turn to `0` (which is a falsish value) and evaluate to false, triggering `hello()`, and for the rest it will trigger `hey()`